# search address based on city name google autocomplete api

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am using google autocomplete api in my web application. I want to search only the addresses for a particular city, like if choose Bangalore as city name then autocomplete should show only the places present in Bangalore. Below code is used to search only the cities in a country,

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

  var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'], //search only cities 
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'in'
    } //In the Country India only
  };
  var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('city'));

  google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = places.getPlace();
    var address = place.formatted_address;
  });
});
```

But I want a feature something of this sort,

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

   var options = {
     types: ['(address)'], // search only address here
     componentRestrictions: {
       city: 'Bangalore'
     } //For Bangalore city only
   };
   var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('city'));

   google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function() {
     var place = places.getPlace();
     var address = place.formatted_address;
   });
 });
```

Comment: Read up about the bounds option. It will bias your search towards bangalore. You'll need the boundary coordinateso but that's simple.

Comment: Ok I will try that..